# Media player 1004 error on galaxy s3

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a videoview that displays content from the web. 
When I play on the nexus 7 with Android 4.2 it works fine, but when I play it on the GS3 ir return an error 1004 IO Error.
Does anyone has any idea why is this happening?

If you need the code I will post it here.
Thanks

Comment: have you found anything for this?

Comment: hi! any updates on this? same thing happens to me only on galaxy s3 when trying to play a stream with media player

Comment: -1004 is an IO Error in Stagefright, the Android multimedia framework. Unfortunately it could be anything from an issue with a decoder to an issue with a Samsung modification in Stagefright that does not exist in Nexus 7. Have you tried playing the content in another app on GS3, e.g. the default video player? If it's a hardware decoder issue you could try with an app that is bundled with software decoders, MX Player had that last I looked. If it's an issue with the decoders, perhaps you can adapt your content.

Comment: Any code or error logs to share? -1004, as stated above, is an I/O error. I generally only see this when the MediaPlayer reaches an unexpected EOF (e.g. it attempts to play a partially downloaded file and reaches the end of the part), never with progressive HTTP download. I suppose it could happen if the content-length header of the HTTP response is not accurate?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was trying to stream an Audio and play it in my application and I had the same error only on Samsung devices. I think they have modified the Android Media Player core and that caused some problem.

What I did for a solution is, I'm checking if the manufacturer of the device is Samsung and pop a dialog window saying that your device does not support streaming. And I download the audio and then play downloaded audio.

I needed an urgent solution and couldn't find a better solution.
Hope it helps.